# Analytical Solution for a Second-Order Nonlinear Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In the frame of semiconductor physics, I find myself in front of a smart but difficult second-order nonlinear ODE :
\begin{equation}
\tag{$E$-ODE}
\label{eq:E-ODE}
\boxed{
\phi_T \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 E}{\mathrm{d}{x}^2} + E \frac{\mathrm{d}{E}}{\mathrm{d}{x}} - \frac{e N_D}{\varepsilon} E = \kappa
\text{.}
}
\end{equation}
I prefer to consider general boundary conditons, as I am looking for an general analytical solution.

Equation can be rewritten as

\begin{equation*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 E}{\mathrm{d}{x}^2}
= -\frac{1}{\phi_T} E \frac{\mathrm{d}{E}}{\mathrm{d}{x}} +  \frac{e N_D}{\varepsilon \phi_T} E + \frac{\kappa}{\phi_T}
\text{.}
\end{equation*}
Setting
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& y \left( x \right) \equiv E \left( x \right) \\
& a \equiv -\frac{1}{\phi_T} \\
& b \equiv \frac{e N_D}{\varepsilon \phi_T} \\
& c \equiv \frac{\kappa}{\phi_T}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d}{x}^2} = a y \frac{\mathrm{d}{y}}{\mathrm{d}{x}} + b y + c
\end{equation*}
Using shortened notations for derivatives:
\begin{equation}
\tag{$y$-ODE}
\label{eq:y-ODE}
\boxed{
y'' = a y y' + b y + c
\text{.}
}
\end{equation}

Here are my attempts :

- it is a second-order nonlinear differential equation;
- it is an autonomous equation : $y'' = F \left( y, y' \right)$;
- it is a Liénard equation : 
  \begin{equation}
  \tag{Liénard}
  \label{eq:Liénard}
  y'' + f \left( y \right) y' + g \left( y \right) = 0
  \text{,}
  \end{equation}
  with $f \left( y \right) = - a y$  and  $g \left( y \right) = - b y - c$.
- with the substitution $w = y'$, it is an Abel equation of the second kind :
  \begin{equation}
  \tag{Abel}
  \label{eq:Abel}
  w w'_{y} + f \left( y \right) w + g \left( y \right) = 0
  \end{equation}

I have tried searching in dedicated textbooks, for instance in Polyanin *Handbook of Exact Solutions for Ordinary Differential Equations*, but I have got the impression that my ODE has no *analytical* solution...

What do you think? Does one among you see or know one way to solve this equation?

Under request, I might provide boundary conditions for some specific problem.

**Remark**: I am familiar with numerical solving of ODE's, but this is not what I am looking for here.

Many thanks forward,

Léopold

Comment: i think your equation is an object for studies, i haven't found an analytical solution

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer, I will keep that in mind! Which way(s) have you (quickly) tried? You searched in your favorite ODE textbook or explored some usual method to deal with such kind of ODE?

Comment: One thing to wonder about is the possibility of periodic solutions, indeed, the possibility of just one periodic solution. Along with the fourth edition of Nonlinear Ordinary Differential Equations, by Jordan and Smith, there is a problem book with solutions, Nonlinear Ordinary Differential Equations: Problems and Solutions: A Sourcebook for Scientists and Engineers (Oxford Texts in Applied and Engineering Mathematics)
D. W. Jordan; Peter Smith, seems published 2007.

Comment: Thank you Will for your answer. Well, in this case, I know from physics that the solution of this ODE for electric field is hardly ever periodic.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=ay\frac{dy}{dx}+by+c$$
This is autonomous ODE. One can reduce it to the first order, thanks to the usual change :

$\frac{dy}{dx}=u(y) \quad\to\quad \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=u\frac{du}{dy}\quad\to\quad u\frac{du}{dy}=a\,y\,u(y)+b\,y+c$

This is an Abel's ODE of the second kind.

The change $\quad u(y)=\frac{1}{v(y)}\quad$ leads to an Abel's ODE of the first kind :
$$\frac{dv}{dy}=-(b\,y+c)v^3-a\,y\,v^2$$
For further progress, see :

https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2011/387429/#sec2

Comment: Many thanks, your link seems very serious and this is already quite advanced calculus for me. I take a look at it tomorrow with a clear head, and I will get back to you.

Comment: Hello. I quickly get stuck with the calculus. Especially, do you know how I can extract, obtain $x(\xi)$ and $\xi(x)$ from $$x = \int f_3 E^2 \mathrm{d}\xi \quad E = \exp\left( \int \left( f_1 - \frac{f_2^2}{f_3}  \right) \mathrm{d}x \right)$$? Note that $\xi \equiv y$, and that their $x$ is different from our $x$.

Comment: and that $f_3 (\xi) = - b \xi - c$, $f_2 (\xi) = - a \xi$ and $f_1 = f_0 = 0$.

Comment: $$\int \left(f_1-\frac{f_2^2}{f_3} \right)d\xi = \int \frac{a^2\xi^2}{b\xi+c}d\xi =\frac{a^2}{2b^3}\left(2c^2\ln(b\xi+c)+b\xi(b\xi-2c) \right) $$
$$E=(b\xi+c)^{a^2c^2/b^3}\exp\left(\frac{a^2}{2b}(b\xi+c)\xi \right)$$
$$x=-\int (b\xi+c)^{1+2a^2c^2/b^3}\exp\left(\frac{a^2}{b}(b\xi+c)\xi \right)d\xi$$
As in the general case, we are stuck by an integral without closed form. All depends on the kind of functions $f_1(\xi),f_2(\xi),f_3(\xi)$. The method is of interest on theoretical view point. But in the majority of  practical cases, the next steps are implicit.

Comment: In fact, the key question is : what is the aim of the calculus? Suppose that, in a favourable case, an  analytical solution be obtained (on the form of implicit or parametric equations). These non-explicit equations require numerical calculus to be used. Then, why not directly solve the ODE thanks to numerical methods? The interest to an analytical solving of the ODE(when it is possible) is purely theoretical. It is a common fact that many ODEs are not solvable on closed form. I am afraid that it is the case here. As you know, other empirical approches are usual especially in physics.

Comment: Hello again, thanks for the details. A short question about it : what does allow you to integrate with respect to $\xi$ and not $x$, to find $E$? I would rather expect a change of variable such as $$\int \left( f_1 (\xi(x)) - \frac{f_2^2 (\xi(x))}{f_3 (\xi(x))}  \right) \mathrm{d}x = \int \left( f_1 (\xi) - \frac{f_2^2 (\xi)}{f_3 (\xi)}  \right) \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\xi} \mathrm{d}\xi$$ which led me to the impression that even the proposed substitution yields to a kind of "coupled" problem. Anyway, all this gets a matter of details following your last post that I am answering to below.

Comment: What is the aim of the calculus? Well, this is quite a long story. My ODE is quite general in the sense that only weaks assumptions were made to obtain it from fundamental physics equations (Maxwell and semiconductor equations). For one academic (but instructive) case, the boundary conditions are such that the solution is actually $$E(x) = E_0 = - \frac{\kappa \varepsilon}{e N_D}.$$ This trivial solution can be obtain without solving the complete problem, by decoupling it by introducing an additionnal assumption (that I actually wished to "proof" with my general approach). I hope this is clear

Comment: Indeed, I hoped for a closed-form solution. I totally agree with your related remarks. As soon as the "analytical" methodology leads to implicit equations or integral, it loses most of its interest, at least for a physicist or an engineer (unlike the dedicated mathematician). I think that we have to accept your conclusion which is that my ODE is not analytically solvable, unfortunately. Do you think that you could spend a few minutes to edit your original answer with your additional developments and remarks, so that I can tick it as "accepted"? Many thanks again.